# material ui problem related to addcircleoutlineicon

Tags: material-ui

Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./src/Component/login.js 6:0-58

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@mui/material/LockOutlined' in 'D:\Uni Notes\Model\new\src\Component'

ERROR

src\Component\container.js
Line 60:16:  'container' is not defined  no-undef

src\Component\signup.js
Line 19:26:  'AddCircleOutlineOutlinedIcon' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Comment: did you solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Import your icon from Mui-icons and not @mui/material.

```
import AddCircleOutlineOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/AddCircleOutlineOutlined';
```

If you not install Mud icons yet :

```
npm i @mui/icons-material
```

To import, you can copy your path here
https://mui.com/components/material-icons/?query=AddCircleOutline&theme=Outlined